# Join Tables without equal fields

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm using BigQuery to generate Google Analytics reports. I would like to create a view with total page views and total page views in the last 30 days for each "pages" I have. I can successfuly do it for a single page but I'm getting errors when I try for all pages at the same time. I understand why but I'm not sure if I can, and how to do it for all of my pages in a single query.

Here is the query I use to fetch the data for a single page :

```
SELECT
   (SELECT (SELECT sum(pageviews)
    FROM `centiva_ga_stats_page_views.report`
    WHERE pagepath LIKE '%28848290%')) as pages_views_all_time,

   (SELECT (SELECT sum(pageviews)
    FROM `centiva_ga_stats_page_views.report`
    WHERE pagepath LIKE '%28848290%' 
    AND date > TIMESTAMP_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL -30 DAY))) as page_views_30_days
```

When I keep hardcoding my `page id` the query run but obviously generate the same results for all the differents pages using this query:

```
SELECT ins.NO_INSCRIPTION,
    (SELECT (SELECT sum(pageviews)
FROM `centiva_ga_stats_page_views.report`
WHERE pagepath LIKE '%28848290%')) as pages_views_all_time,
(SELECT (SELECT sum(pageviews)
FROM `centiva_ga_stats_page_views.report`
WHERE pagepath LIKE '%28848290%' AND date > TIMESTAMP_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL -30 DAY))) as page_views_30_days
FROM staging_remaxlist.Inscriptions ins
```

I tried using `CONCAT('%',ins.NO_INSCRIPTION,'%')` to replace my hardcoded wildcard `page id` but I get this error :

> LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join.**

I kind of understand why but I have no solution to make my query work.

The `pagepath` field contains my `page id` but can be anything (no standard format)

Any help is appreciated thank you!

Here is my database schema simplified :

**Table staging_remaxlist.Inscriptions**

```
Field             Type
id                INTEGER 
no_inscription    STRING
```

**Table centiva_ga_stats_page_views.report**

```
Field         Type
date          TIMESTAMP
start_date    TIMESTAMP
end_date      TIMESTAMP
pagepath      STRING
pageviews     INTEGER
```

Examples of `centiva_ga_stats_page_views.report.pagepath` :

```
/en/house-for-sale-laurentides/350-rue-de-lucerne-ste-adele-17269832.rmx
/en/propertyview/12616898
/en/our-properties/gatineau-gatineau/181-rue-duquette-o/12078284
/fr/showproperty/18726771
/wp-content/plugins/hydrogene-wp/public/cache/16543327fr.html
/Properties/enhanceddetails/4e04ec20-M11699403?language=FR
```

anything that can contain the `staging_remaxlist.Inscriptions.NO_INSCRIPTION` field that is an integer ranging from 7 to 8 (we should expect it to go to 9) characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the updated schema. It sounds like what you really want is a regex match of pages, and to then use that match value to join with your inscriptions table. The below query should work:

```
WITH total_pageviews AS (
    SELECT 
      CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(pagepath, r"[0-9]+") AS INT64) AS pp
      , SUM(pageviews) AS total_pageviews
    FROM `centiva_ga_stats_page_views.report`
    WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(pagepath, r"[0-9]+")
    GROUP BY CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(pagepath, r"[0-9]+") AS INT64)
)
SELECT pp, total_pageviews, SUM(pageviews) AS page_views_30_days
FROM total_pageviews JOIN `staging_remaxlist.Inscriptions` ins 
  ON ga.pp = ins.NO_INSCRIPTION
WHERE date > TIMESTAMP_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL -30 DAY)
GROUP BY pp, total_pageviews
```

Previous query:

```
WITH page_views_all AS (
    SELECT pagepath AS pp, sum(pageviews) AS page_views_all_time
    FROM `centiva_ga_stats_page_views.report`
    WHERE pagepath LIKE '%28848290%'
    GROUP BY pagepath
)

SELECT pp, page_views_all_time, SUM(pageviews) AS page_views_30_days
FROM page_views_all pva
  INNER JOIN `centiva_ga_stats_page_views.report` pv
  ON pva.pp = pv.pagepath
WHERE pagepath LIKE '%28848290%' 
  AND date > TIMESTAMP_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL -30 DAY)
GROUP BY pp, page_views_all_time
```

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted, I'm looking for the SUM of the pageviews for all "page id" (staging_remaxlist.Inscriptions.NO_INSCRIPTION) contained in the staging_remaxlist.Inscriptions table.

Comment: Ah, OK. I'm sure we can get to the final answer. It would be helpful if you could provide a description of the schemas of the tables so that it's easier to picture what needs to be pulled out

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. Please check if the above new query meets your needs